# Export binary images from Spark DataFrame to Azure storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Databricks to validate my ML image classification model. I have a DataFrame with the results of my analysis, which contains some images in each raw. The Dataframe is big and when displayed, the table is truncated. I would like to export the result images for further processing, possibly to Azure storage, so that each row (single image) is stored to a separate file. Downloading the result as CSV does not work - the result is also truncated.
As the documentation says:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html

*"Binary file data source does not support writing a DataFrame back to the original files."*

So what are the options left? Any intermediate format from which I could retrieve the image files?

Answer (score 0):

> "Binary file data source does not support writing a DataFrame back to the original files."

Yes, you can't write the images in it's original file after processing.

You need to create a new file at the destination location, in this case Azure blob storage.

Change your approach as per given below:

1. Read an individual image from the dataframe.
2. Process the image using python image processing library, like `cv2`.
3. Store the image using `cv2.imwrite()` method. Example: `cv2.imwrite(filename, image)`

This way, by using iteration in python you can read individual image, process it using `cv2` module and store it at specified path.